# Casting multidimensional data in R into a data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some percentage based comparisons across different groups in a criminal sentencing data set (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1156404/wightCrimRecords.csv)

I have a data in an array of the form:

```
    $Female
    x
                             Burglary                 Criminal Damage and Arson 
                          0.004950495                               0.017326733 
                     Driving Offences                                    Murder 
                          0.371287129                               0.000000000
    $Male
    x
                             Burglary                 Criminal Damage and Arson 
                          0.013001083                               0.058504875 
                     Driving Offences                                    Murder 
                          0.303358613                               0.000000000

    $`Not Stated`
    x
                             Burglary                 Criminal Damage and Arson 
                            0.0000000                                 0.0000000 
                     Driving Offences                                    Murder 
                            0.1111111                                 0.0000000
```

This was derived from the original data as follows:

```
iw=read.csv("~/data/recordlevel.csv")
iwp=tapply(iw$Offence_type,iw$AGE,function(x){prop.table(table(x))})
```

What I would like to do is generate a single data frame that contains a gender column, a frequency column, and rows corresponding to Burglary, Murder etc.

I can extract a single datatable from the multidimensional array, eg using:

```
iwpF =data.frame(iwp['Female'])
```

which generates a separate row for each offence and columns referring to offence type and frequency, but can't see how to generate a single datatable.

PS I was also wondering whether it's possible to pull out even more structured data, that for example counts the percentages of offence type sex and age group, so for example I could lookup up what percentage of convictions for males in the 35+ age range are related to murder.

Comment: Is there a discrepancy in your code between AGE and sex? It looks like you are showing tapply() function by AGE, but are referring to it by gender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I followed the PS part of your question, but maybe this will get you on the right path. The trick is to use `melt()` to get the data into long format, then use `ddply()` to group by:

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
iw <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1156404/wightCrimRecords.csv")
iw.m <- melt(iw, id.vars = "sex", measure.vars = "Offence_type")
ddply(iw.m, "sex", function(x) as.data.frame(prop.table(table(x$value))))
```

Gives us:

```
          sex                                      Var1        Freq
1      Female                                  Burglary 0.004950495
2      Female                 Criminal Damage and Arson 0.017326733
3      Female                          Driving Offences 0.371287129
...
50      Other                           Supply of drugs 0.000000000
51      Other                             Vehicle Crime 0.000000000
52      Other                             Violent Crime 0.000000000
```

**EDIT - after reading the PS again, I think this is what you had in mind:**

```
iw.m <- melt(iw, id.vars = c("sex", "AGE"), measure.vars = "Offence_type")
ddply(iw.m, c("sex", "AGE"), function(x) as.data.frame(prop.table(table(x$value))))

           sex   AGE                                      Var1        Freq
1       Female 18-24                                  Burglary 0.011764706
2       Female 18-24                 Criminal Damage and Arson 0.047058824
3       Female 18-24                          Driving Offences 0.188235294
....
```

You can obviously continue to add ID variables which then get passed into plyr to group on to any level of detail that is sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: That's wonderful, thanks. Spot on. I can see I need to get my head round the melt function and plyr routines ...

Comment: @psychemedia - definitely worth the time investment in my opinion. Hadley has put together some nice work on both packages [here](http://had.co.nz/reshape/) and [here](http://plyr.had.co.nz/)